# SvelteJS components with or without onMount

Tags: javascript, performance, svelte, svelte-3

Can you help me understand what's the difference here between these two components:

REPL: https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-onmount-or-not-yhu91

- With onMount:

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  let canRender;

  onMount(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      canRender = true;
    }, 1000);
  });
</script>

{#if canRender}I'm with onMount!{/if}
```

- Without onMount:

```
<script>
  let canRender;

  setTimeout(() => {
    canRender = true;
  }, 1000);
</script>

{#if canRender}I'm without onMount!{/if}
```

I mean in many cases I need to handle the creation of component with a boolean (`canRender`) because of many events or because I'm waiting some delay from props.

How about performances?

What's the difference in the final code?

Do I have another way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

In **Svelte** `onMount()` is a **lifecycle event**. That means `onMount()` fires when

> runs after the component is first rendered to the DOM

*source: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount*

That means that in your first case you start the `setTimeout()` when the component is first rendered, in the second case you start the `setTimeout()` when JS reaches that line of code.

Most of the time you won't see a difference in time (the **mounting** will be very fast), but if you do a lot of things before rendering, then `onMount()` will be delayed.

The main difference between the two is not about performance, but what is **available** when you run your function:
- if you run it without `onMount()` a lot of things (variables, attributes, etc.) won't be available
- if you run it within `onMount()` the component will be "ready" to use

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain this better: "what is available when you run your function"? If I have an `export delay` it is available in my code with or without onMount, right?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not very skilled in Svelte - but the lifecycle of a component means that certain functions are run in an order (like setting up attributes of a component), and if you call a function that references an attribute not set up, then your function is going fail. In **Vue** for example you cannot call a **computed** attribute in the **beforeCreated** lifecycle event - computed attributes simply do not exist at that time. (I know it's not Svelte - but lifecycle is lifecycle in all frameworks :) ) `onMount()` ensures that everything is set up for DOM render (according to docs).

Comment: @FredHors so for your exact question (`export delay`) - I'm not sure, I'd need to work with **Sevelte** more. The thing, though: `onMount()` **ensures** that all the init events happened before it that were supposed to happen. Your functions/variables may be available before this event, but you might run into errors, as this is not "for sure". Simply think of `onMount()` as a trigger that lets you know that the component is set up, data/functions are accessible, and you can work with those. It's kinda' like a callback at that event.

Answer (score 3):

Think of `onMount` as an `onload` handler. When a component is loaded: its script is run, CSS parsed, and HTML added to the DOM, then `onMount` is fired.

So in your example it won't make any difference. And yes, passed in properties are available outside of `onMount`.

But if you tried to access the DOM (either by using something like `getElementById` or using `bind:this` to bind an element to a variable), that will not be available to a top level script, but will be available in `onMount`.

Here's a REPL that shows this:

https://svelte.dev/repl/eaa7656f6a98479a82b0a3ad2d105b9b?version=3.29.4